# Obtener informacion de matriz

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

estoy trabajando en crear un software para optimizar barras, tuberías, etc. Estoy utilizando C# en Visual Studio 2019.

La matriz donde guardo la información que introduce el usuario se muestra adjunta, la columna “0” contiene la **longitud** de cada barra y la columna “1” el **id** de cada barra, o código o tipo si se le puede llamar.

Necesito saber si existe una clase o método que me devuelva el número de tipos de barras (tipos = id), si no me explique bien, cuantos id se encuentra en la columna id, que para este caso son 2, el 1015A y el 9014.

Saludos

[image: Matriz]

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, te invito a mirar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Por favor siempre coloca tu código y lo que hayas intentado. Saludos

Comment: [tag:c++] o [tag:c#], son lenguajes muy distintos que ofrecerán soluciones muy distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes simplificar tu código si te apoyas en el uso de Listas. Para ello has de incluir la siguiente librería using System.Collections.Generic en tu cabecera y luego el código quedaría así:

```
 string[] vec_1 = new string[10];

 vec_1[0] = "1015A";
 vec_1[1] = "1015A";
 vec_1[2] = "9014";
 vec_1[3] = "1015A";
 vec_1[4] = "1060";
 vec_1[5] = "1015B";
 vec_1[6] = "9014";
 vec_1[7] = "1060";
 vec_1[8] = "1020";
 vec_1[9] = "9014";
 // Creamos una lista auxiliar
 List<string> ColumnLst = new List<string>();
 for (int h = 0; h < vec_1.Length; h++)
 {
     // Hacemos uso del método Contains para saber si el elemento fue añadido o no,
     // si no existe en la lista lo añadimos.
     if (!ColumnLst.Contains(vec_1[h])) ColumnLst.Add(vec_1[h]);
 }

 // Número de elementos distintos en columna
 int result = ColumnLst.Count;
```

La propiedad *Count* de la lista nos dará el número de elementos distintos, a demás la propia lista nos dice cuales son esos elementos:

```
foreach(string item in ColumnLst)
{
    // Imrime cada elemento 
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si, para este caso tendrías que hacer un contador de coincidencias puede ser `int contadorID = 0`, éste ayudara a que cada vez que encuentres una coincidencia en tu recorrido del arreglo, que puedes fácilmente realizarlo en un ciclo `for` o `foreach` agregue +1 al contador y de esa forma podrías saber cuando un elemento coincide. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
 int contadorcoincidencias = 0;
            int variableabuscar = 3;

            int[,] matriz = new int[3, 2] { { 9, 99 }, { 3, 3 }, { 3, 55 } };

            foreach (int i in matriz)
            {
                if (variableabuscar == i)
                    contadorcoincidencias++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de coincidencias: "+contadorcoincidencias);

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Daniel gracias, el ejemplo que muestra cuenta las cantidades de veces que se cumplen la sentencia if, eso lo entiendo correctamente, pero no es lo que necesito.
A lo mejor no me explique bien arriba, en otras palabras, lo que necesito es determinar la cantidad de diferencias de datos en una determina columna.
En tu ejemplo tenemos una matriz de 3 filas y 2 columnas (3x2), con esos mismos valores, se puede decir que en la primera columna tenemos: 9,3,3 - esto significa que hay dos (2) números diferentes, 9 y 3. es lo que necesito un método o clase ya en C# que devuelva el valor 2.

Answer (score 0):

ya resolvi mi problema, les dejo el codigo por si alguien lo necesita, el valor de retorno es la variable contador1, para este ejemplo retorna el valor de (5), ya que son 5 valores diferentes que contiene el arreglo:

```
 int contador1 = 0;
 string[] vec_1 = new string[10];

        vec_1[0] = "1015A";
        vec_1[1] = "1015A";
        vec_1[2] = "9014";
        vec_1[3] = "1015A";
        vec_1[4] = "1060";
        vec_1[5] = "1015B";
        vec_1[6] = "9014";
        vec_1[7] = "1060";
        vec_1[8] = "1020";
        vec_1[9] = "9014";

        for (int h = 0; h < vec_1.Length; h++)
        {
            if (vec_1[h] != "")
            {
                contador1++;                    

                for (int x = h + 1; x < vec_1.Length; x++)
                {                                                
                     if (vec_1[h] == vec_1[x])
                     {
                        vec_1[x] = "";
                     }                        
                }
            }
        }
```